# Is there a (free) GUI to setup transport calculations using SIESTA?

Tags: software, siesta, transport, graphical-user-interface, open-source

I am very interested in doing transport calculation with SIESTA.

My problem is that it is a little hard for me to understand and setup the input files to be used with TranSIESTA (the module that do the transmission and I-V curve simulations).

Do you know any software/server/GUI that can prepare such input? I am thinking in something in the same direction like Virtual NanoLab from the [QuantumATK](https://www.synopsys.com/silicon/quantumatk.html).

Here is an [example](https://quantumwise.com/documents/manuals/ATK-12.8/VNLTutorial/index.html/chap.gnr.html) of how the old Virtual NanoLab works.

Note: I am involved in many other projects that demand huge amounts of time dedicated to them. That's why I am looking to speed up some things here.

Answer (score 14):

They do not have an easy interface, however, there are some tutorials and examples that can be used, you can use as an input parameter:  [github.com/siesta-project/tutorials](https://github.com/siesta-project/tutorials).

The input file is in .fdf, you can try to generate only the structure through nanolab> 2015 with commercial or academic version.

But the calculator will always be set manually, with the flags themselves.

Answer (score 13):

This is not the exact response to your question, but I would like to present a very good youtube channel [QuantumNerd](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgQPek4ZSo_yL7wEjIhxvfA). Its content is vast and interesting, concerning materials simulation. Recently, he posted a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2e1TWx6DHs) about a project of making multi-platform GUI for Quantum ESPRESSO, he mentioned though the possibility of growing the project to other DFT engines.

Answer (score 7):

### GUI4dft - A SIESTA oriented GUI

[GUI4dft](https://github.com/sozykinsa/GUI4dft) is a new  Graphical User Interface for Density Functional Theory  for users of SIESTA. GUI4dft is written in Python language, falls under an MIT license and is a free cross-platform software.  GUI4dft allows the user to work with standard SIESTA files and prepare manuscript-quality figures of the atomic structure and properties such as three-dimensional charge density distributions, DOS, PDOS, and band structure. The program is cross-platform due to the fact that it is written in Python 3 and uses the PyQt5, OpenGL, Scipy, Numpy and Scikit-image  [1](https://github.com/sozykinsa/GUI4dft) modules available in major operating systems.

[image]

References:

1. [Sozykin, S. A. "GUI4dft—A SIESTA oriented GUI." Computer Physics Communications 262 (2021): 107843](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2021.107843).

Comment: @NikeDattani :)